# I have a data set with postive negative values computing LN in awk using if statement conditions

Tags: awk, logs, math

I have large datasets in where the natural log (LN) is being computed. However, there is many cases where there are negative values and awk is kicking out a warning line for each occurrence and will not print the new field. I already know how to compute and add the additional field. However, I am uncertain as how I can get awk to print the values for the positive data points and print some sort of missing data identifier such as NR where the data is negative in value. In this case the data will be $11 and the (LN) output will print in $12.
thank you

```
QUEENS_DEC,5/26/2002,3.06, ,16.61342593,0.830833333,20020526,0,50.5414,0.0391322,50.5805,**3.9236**
QUEENS_DEC,5/27/2002, ,0.8150,19.73148148,0.812083333,20020527,0.0353628,60.0271,0.0382491,60.1007,**4.0960**
QUEENS_DEC,5/28/2002, , ,19.15046296,0.77,20020528,0,58.2595,0.036267,58.2958,**4.0655**
QUEENS_DEC,5/29/2002,1.83, ,21.76388889,0.783333333,20020529,0,66.2101,0.036895,-66.247,**NR**
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `if` test.

For example:

```
awk -F, '
  BEGIN { OFS="," } 
  { if ($11<=0) { $12="NR" } else { $12=log($11) } ; print }
'
```

This will set field 12 to the string "NR" or the the log of field 11, depending on the value seen.

With your input file the output now looks like:

```
QUEENS_DEC,5/26/2002,3.06, ,16.61342593,0.830833333,20020526,0,50.5414,0.0391322,50.5805,3.92357
QUEENS_DEC,5/27/2002, ,0.8150,19.73148148,0.812083333,20020527,0.0353628,60.0271,0.0382491,60.1007,4.09602
QUEENS_DEC,5/28/2002, , ,19.15046296,0.77,20020528,0,58.2595,0.036267,58.2958,4.06553
QUEENS_DEC,5/29/2002,1.83, ,21.76388889,0.783333333,20020529,0,66.2101,0.036895,-66.247,NR
```